# Retrieve all nested values from a key and sub keys till there is no key in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary with elements like this :

```
dict_Test={
   'TEST':{'O','Z'},
   'X':{'A','B','C'},
   'T':{'tit'},
   'C':{'D','E','F','TEST'},
   'F':{'T'}
}
```

I was trying to loop through this dictionary to finally have the root elements with no duplicate element that already exist for example :
find('x') would return {A,B,D,E,tit,O,Z} no element that has a sub element .
I hope it is clear enough
well here is my code in attempt to do that

```
def GetInputs( keyToRetrieve):
   dict = [dict_Test]
   while dict:
      mapping = dict.pop()
      try:
         items = mapping.items()
      except AttributeError:
         continue

      for key, value in items:
         if key == keyToRetrieve:
            return value
         else:
            dict.append(value)

dict_Test={
   'TEST':{'O','Z'},
   'X':{'A','B','C'},
   'T':{'tit'},
   'C':{'D','E','F','TEST'},
   'F':{'T'}
}



inputs={}
i=1
for input in  GetInputs('X'): 
   while True:  
      for inputValue in  input:
         input=GetInputs(inputValue)
         print('[Itter '+str(i)+' ] RelatedInput: '+str(inputValue)+' value: '+str(input)+'__'+str(input==None)) 
         i+=1  
      
         if input==None:
            inputs.update({inputValue:input})
         else :
            input=list(GetInputs(inputValue))
      if input==None:
            break  
         
print('Result: '+str(inputs))
```

My problem is that the loop will stop at level 2

```
[Itter 1 ] RelatedInput: B value: None__True
[Itter 2 ] RelatedInput: C value: {'D', 'E', 'TEST', 'F'}__False
[Itter 3 ] RelatedInput: D value: None__True
[Itter 4 ] RelatedInput: E value: None__True
[Itter 5 ] RelatedInput: TEST value: {'Z', 'O'}__False
[Itter 6 ] RelatedInput: F value: {'T'}__False
[Itter 7 ] RelatedInput: T value: {'tit'}__False
[Itter 8 ] RelatedInput: tit value: None__True
[Itter 9 ] RelatedInput: A value: None__True
Result: {'B': None, 'D': None, 'E': None, 'tit': None, 'A': None}
```

For example here it will not show sub element of 'Test' I m not sure what am I doing wrong and how could I possibly handle the loop

Thanx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this small code not solve the task?

```
def find(x):
    res = []
    for item in dict_Test[x]:
        if item not in dict_Test:
            res.append(item)
        else:
            res.extend(find(item))
    return res


print(find('X'))  # ['B', 'A', 'D', 'O', 'Z', 'tit', 'E']
```

Comment: OMG thanx! this really helped man! I appreciate it ... yes it is a little code .. I am just a newbie here

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck!